# Power Bi DAX: Count rows dynamically and aggregate

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this sample table:

[image: table]

"Running Total" is a MEASURE (NOT a column), and I need to change this measure such that it works when the date column is filtered.

Current code for "Running Total", which generates the above output:
[image: Code for running total]
Issue with the code: It does not work when the "date" column is filtered using a slicer.

I need this output when the date filter is set to 2018-01-01-2023-01-01 for example:

[image: table filtered]

As you can see, 2017 dates are removed, therefore the "Running Total" measure is adjusted accordingly.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ALL() with ALLSELECTED()